# Integration in a finite dimensional vector space

Tags: rt.representation-theory, integration, topological-groups

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional complex vector space. Let $G$ be a compact group with normalized Haar measure $\mu$. In the representation theory of compact groups, I encounter

$$\int_G f(g) \mu(dg)$$

where $f: G \to V$ is a continuous function.

How is this integral definied? I know about the Lebesgue integral for functions with values in $\mathbb{C}$.

Maybe we should fix a base and consider the isomorphism $V \cong \mathbb{C}^n$ and apply the integral in each component? But then it should be shown that this does not depend on the choice of basis. Moreover, choosing a basis is always non-canonical so I might be missing something here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do not want to use coordinate systems, a more intrinsic way to reduce to scalar functions is defining $\int_Gf(g) \mu(dg)$ as the (unique) element $v\in V$ such that for any linear form $\phi\in V^*$ one has $\int_G \langle \phi,f(g)\rangle\mu(dg)=\langle \phi,v\rangle$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is the coordinate definition well-defined actually?

Comment: Yes it is and it is equivalent to Pietro's base-free definition.

Comment: Alright! Thanks both!

Comment: By the way: This definition is also reasonable for infinite-dimensional (topological) vector spaces. This is called [Pettis integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pettis_integral).

Answer (score 1):

Definitely do not pick a basis.  You also don't have to pick an inner product on $V$ or reduce to scalar-valued functions.

You can define integration with respect to a measure in direct way as a limit without having to do any kind of decomposition into real or imaginary parts or positive or negative parts as is often presented for integration of real or complex valued functions.  See the treatment of integration in Lang's "Real and Functional Analysis", where the functions being integrated take values in a Banach space. That applies in particular to functions with the values in a finite-dimensional complex vector space $V$ (which has a canonical Hausdorff topology making it complete for all vector space norms on $V$).

Comment: Thanks, but the first sentence seems a bit strong. It is natural and it works, so why not?

Comment: Picking a basis (the first sentence) is not natural. A finite-dimensional space has no natural basis.

Comment: These two approaches are already in the elementary treatment of real valued functions; Riemann defined his integral by limits, and Darboux somehow simplified Riemann integral's construction into the now popular saga of infimum of upper sums and supremum of lower sums.

Comment: Yes, but many students learn Lebesgue integration in a way that doesn't make them realize that integration with respect to a measure can be handled via limits in place of breaking up the integrand into positive and negative parts.  I am just pointing out to the OP that such an approach to integration with respect to a measure exists, since the OP would likely not have asked the question in the first place if the OP already knew that it is possible.